# Selenium - IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python

[image: Page HTML#1]
[image: Page HTML#2]

Customer Order Function

```
      <input type="button" name="" accesskey="D" value="D" onclick="go('/tips/SO1R1301.do')" class="FunButton">&nbsp;Print Daily Product Audit List

  </td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="TRs">
  <td class="TDs">
      <input type="button" name="" accesskey="B" value="B" onclick="go('/tips/SO1R0601.do')" class="FunButton">&nbsp;Print Order Form Function
  </td>
  <td class="TDs">

      <input type="button" name="" accesskey="E" value="E" onclick="go('/tips/SO1B3401.do')" class="FunButton">&nbsp;Branch Product Order Non-delivery list

  </td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="TRs">
  <td class="TDs">
      <input type="button" name="" accesskey="C" value="C" onclick="go('/tips/SO1M1201.do')" class="FunButton">&nbsp;Branch Closing Process
  </td>
  <td class="TDs">

      <input type="button" name="" accesskey="F" value="F" onclick="go('/tips/SO1B3701.do')" class="FunButton">&nbsp;Statistic Report of Product Sales Qty for Excel

  </td>
  </tr>
```

My code:

```
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//ifram[@name='functionPage"))
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//input[text()='Print Order Form Function']").click()
```

I want to click "B" function and get process IndexError: list index out of range.

Comment: You need to show more html since apparently you have 4 of these buttons i guess from the [4].
Is the path that you shared unique when you search for it ?

Comment: thank you for your reply, i have update more information

Comment: so the new path you put is wrong too since the input doesnt containt the text add the previous path that you had and remove the [4] path since it s incorrect to have since you dont have 4 buttons that have @value = "B" and @class="FunButton"

Comment: i try to use onclick replace but it doesn't work

Comment: Please add your html as code , not as picture so that we can try it out

Comment: i have add html code

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//input[@value='B']").click()
```

instead of

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//input[text()='Print Order Form Function']").click()
```

Comment: i try this method, it not work when i run show this warning
[selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[@value='B']"}
  (Session info: chrome=95.0.4638.69)]